# Suggested virtual disk setting for VMWare VM used as a development environment for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, installation, guidance, vmware

I want to set up my development environment for sharepoint 2013 on a VM; my environment specification are as follow:-

• A laptop with windows 7 professional 64x

• The laptop has 670 GB harddisk

• 32 GB of RAM

• VM workstation

During my creation for a new VM I mount an ISO image representing a windows server 2008 data centre to the VM , but it ask me to provide the following:-

1. Specify the disk capacity , by default it select 40 GB , **so should I modify this number**?
2. Then I have to select between these two options ; Store virtual disk as a single file OR to split virtual disk to multiple files. **So which option I should use**?

Thanks for you e help

Comment: Hi John, I have edited your question title. It should be easier now for other users using search to find the information contained in this question. Feel free to improve it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the disk capacity - you can expand your disk later, by following a procedure described on the VMware support site. Anyway, if space isn't a problem I would just go with an initial capacity of 80-100GB. The point about the disk isn't the capacity, but if you want to pre-allocate the space or grow dynamically. As you can imagine dynamic grow has a little performance loss when compared with a pre-allocated disk, but a pre-allocated disk will eat all the space from the start.

About the single/split file - again it's more a performance factor. AFAIK, splitting the file could have some performance benefit - especially if you can store the files on different disk units. That said, for SP2010 I always use a single pre-allocated file of 80gb, stored on an usb external disk - so you may try something similar for sp2013. Based on the requirement posted by Microsoft, I fear that the main stopper will be the VM ram - followed by disk access. Again, try to move the vm virtualdisk files on a physical hd different from the one your OS runs on.

Comment: +1 for better understanding  fort store virtual disk as a single file and split virtual disk into multiple files.